# Placing just an LED in a circuit?

Tags: led, voltage, current, kirchhoffs-laws

Kirchhoff's law states that “in any closed loop network, the total voltage around the loop is equal to the sum of all the voltage drops within the same loop”

What would happen if you placed a LED with a 2V drop into a circuit with a 12V battery and no resistor, would this work as it breaks Kirchhoff's law? and how would you calculate the current in this circuit?

Then, if you swapped the 12V battery with a 2V battery, what would happen as this is now in line with Kirchoff's law? what would the current be in this circuit?

Thanks.

Comment: If you manage do create a circuit with really no resistance, please tell me

Comment: Well, even if you do, the voltage drop on the LED will be 12V. And it will blow up. 2V is a spec for a *properly* biased LED.

Comment: @PlasmaHH We do it all the time. Weld some NbTi wire in a loop, chill, inject some current and off you go.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I believe the LED won't be cool with the chilling..

Comment: @EugeneSh. They change color at 77K. Kind of fun.

Comment: It will be high, but not for long. A 12V car battery has internal resistance of maybe 0.05 ohms, the wiring perhaps something similar. That's 100A if the LED had 2V across it. But the LED will end up dropping probably 11V+, and conducting maybe 10A (so, 110W), so it will briefly attempt imitate a 100W incandescent lamp in its final moments. Probably the bonding wire will burn off with a brief flash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would not break Kirchoff's law, but it would break the LED. Take a look at the current-voltage curve for a typical LED:

[image: I-V for a typical LED]

Here, around the forward operating voltage (Vd) the current (i) increases vastly with tiny changes in voltage. Vd in your case is 2V, typical for standard red, green and yellow LEDs. At 20V (not shown on the graph) the theoretical current would be phenomenal! This would be enough to vaporise most of the LED's constituent elements. In reality, what would happen is that the LED would shine very brightly for a very short time indeed before letting out its ["magic smoke"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke). This is the very reason that we include current limiting resistors in LED circuits.

If you swap the 12V battery for a 2V battery, things get interesting. Now we're right where the dotted line above Vd sits - small changes in voltage give large changes in current. Here, the current is defined by an exponential equation with a strong dependency on temperature. We won't know what the actual operating current is, but it will be strongly dependent on the exact battery voltage and the temperature, along with the battery's non-ideal series resistance (acting a bit like the series resistor we normally use with a diode). However no engineer worth their salt would ever drive a LED like this. LEDs are very sensitive to voltage changes, and their brightness (the parameter we want to control) is strongly related to their current. Hence LEDs are always driven with current in mind - be that with a statically chosen resistor or a specialised circuit with a feedback loop designed to keep current constant.

Comment: Thanks @stefandz, so in a circuit with just an LED and 12V battery, 12V still flows throw the circuit (for a brief time at least), and the current would be dictated by the current-voltage curve?

Comment: The current voltage curve along with the internal resistance of the battery + wires. The two constraints would form a pair of simultaneous equations with one solution for current.

Comment: @RJSmith92 Voltage doesn't flow, current does. If you blow up the LED, the voltage will still be there.

Comment: @Mast True, I should have worded it better.

Comment: @stefandz Thanks for the help with this. Final thing, the simple circuit from yesterday, with a 12V battery, 2V/20mA LED and 500 Ohm resistor, the current in the circuit was 20mA (I = 10/500 Ohm), so that's how the current was calculated. How does this tie in with the current-voltage curve? What's dictating the current in the circuit it?

Comment: @RJSmith92 - this should really go with the other question, but the answer is... the resistor! Since we know that the forward voltage of the LED will be around 2V no matter what the current, then we know the voltage across the resistor. This gives us the current (Ohm's law) and from KCL (Kirchoff's current law) we know the current through the LED. This divorces us from the I-V curve's sensitivity, puts us in control and makes calculations simple.

Comment: @stefandz, right got it, I think. With a resistor controlling the current, the voltage drop of the LED will always be around 2v (as shown in the diagram in your answer), but without a resistor in the circuit, there's nothing to limit the current so the LED will have a voltage drop of 12V (in line with KVL)and an incredibly high current for a small moment before it pops?

Comment: That's about the size of it - provided that the chosen resistor limits to current to within the LED's specified current.

Comment: Hi @stefandz, me again! Just reading over my posts and I noticed Eugene Sh. commented that with a 12V battery and just an LED, the voltage drop across the LED will be 12V, and it has 7 upvotes. Is this wrong? Is it not what you said the other day regarding Internal Resistance, and the external voltage of the battery available will be 2V and the voltage drop of the LED will be 2V?

Comment: The key point to that post is "even if you do" i.e. even if you do create a circuit with no resistance. However, Eugene SH is certainly right in saying that no matter what the resistance, 2V is the specification for a correctly biased LED. I am tempted to set this experiment up and do a scope capture so you can see what actually happens.

Comment: @stefandz Ahh OK, so in theory if you could create a circuit with no resistance the drop would be 12V, but in reality, the drop will be around 2V?

Comment: Somewhere between the two - depending on the series resistance. But also, the drop will be completely unstable - I did this experiment today with a 12V LED and a 1 ohm internal resistance dummy - the result was 11.5V dropped for 1 second before the LED started to disintegrate, the current dropped off (along with the voltage) fluttering around before it finally popped. BTW, the only really useful design lesson in all of this is that when driving LEDs you need to consider both voltage and current, and keep both within the Absolute Maximum ratings in the datasheet.

Comment: @stefandz, Interesting, thanks for doing that. Did you mean a 12V battery? and the LED dropped 11.5V?

Comment: 12V power supply and - 1 ohm led to simulate the internal resistance of the battery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27095/discussion-between-rjsmith92-and-stefandz).

Answer (score 2):

If you connect a standard LED across a 12 volt battery, a very large current (determined primarily by the wiring resistance) will flow briefly and the LED will vanish in a puff of smoke. KVL will be respected as long as the LED is intact.

The actual voltage across a lit LED is determined primarily by its composition (and therefore colour), and is highly unlikely to be 2.000 volts.  The voltage will vary with current and temperature, so connecting a bare LED directly to a voltage source is a Bad Thing.  LEDs must always be driven from a voltage source higher then their forward voltage, with a current limiting resistor or other current control device.

Answer (score 2):

A real circuit has non-idealities that would apply to this case:

- An LED voltage is not exact: the current through a 2V LED will increase above the typical specified current as the voltage increases above 2V. 12V will cause the LED to fail.
- All of the wires have some resistance: If the LED melts from passing too much power, it may become a very low resistance.  Now the 12V supply may be driving perhaps 0.1 ohm resistance. If you have a 1500 Watt power that can drive 120 Amps and all of your wires are huge, this could theoretically be a stable state, but more likely parts of the circuit or power supply will start to melt until it is an open circuit.  If the LED failure did not cause a short circuit but instead an open circuit, it is not as bad as there is no longer any closed circuit and no current will flow.
- Also, the power supply has a maximum current: if you have a nice current-limited supply and you set the maximum current to 20mA, it will not actually be a 12V supply anymore, but more like a 2V supply. If the current limit is much higher or there is no current limit, see above.

Answer (score 0):

LED does have resistance, as well as the battery and almost anything else that can be connected to each other; no one knows "What would happen if you placed a LED with a 2V drop into a circuit with a 12V battery and no resistor".